# How can I simply pull feeds from Mac Calendar public calendar, in FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to pulls some feeds from a public calendar from Mac Calendar, using FullCalendar, but don't get it right.

My code is this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{
        url: 'webcal://p06-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/BiZWqETAhbzMYxKjzH1c44hk6XTywURUK8Y_sGHpIpK0rw0hblNFAgPVME8lYwSmqFzoQtQ6WEeZAenhCD0xkdrJVd7d76kMltzL7hcyjVA', // use the `url` property
        color: 'yellow',    // an option!
        textColor: 'black'  // an option!
    }
    // any other sources...
    ]
})
```

The calendar is there, but no events are pulled. I can't figure out if I should use json or whatever. Is my feed even valid for this jQuery Plugin?

PS:
After so many days of research, I was amazed at how I couldn't find a simple tool to have a basic calendar on my website thats pulls the feed from a public calendar I got in Mac Calendar!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the response isn't valid. You can check the response using the Google Chrome inspector or Firebug on Firefox. 
You are going to need a server-side script to get the data from iCal, convert for the fullcalendar format (here documentation for the "event" object http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) and return a JSON formatted response for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if your format is correct. [Format online](http://jsonformat.com/)